# Windows Form App for loop not working

Tags: c#, windows, forms, for-loop

```
int i = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 10; j < 1000; j = j + 1)
    {
        string y = i.ToString();
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").SetAttribute("value", y);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This is the section of code I'm working with in a windows form application
I want it to input the value and show it going up however it just jumps to the end and puts the last output instead of counting up.
Some people said to use timers but I haven't been able to get them to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to call `webBrowser1.Refresh()` after setting the attribute. This will force a redraw. It will however (as the deleted answer pointed out) update too quickly to see the effect though. What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: It will just count up in google search box. Just for testing.

Comment: the Refresh stops the action if I put it in the for loop without displaying anything

Answer (score 0):

You're locking up the UI thread with your loop, so that it doesn't update the control until it's done with its work. You end up only seeing the final value, when the loop is complete and the UI refreshes.

Take a look at using a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control instead. You can tell it to raise an event at regular intervals, and it'll allow your UI to be updated correctly.

Add a `Timer` to your `Form` and then insert the following code into your constructor to try it out. Currently, it updates your element every 1 ms (in reality, it won't be that fast).

```
int i = 0;
int j = 10;

timer1.Interval = 1;
timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    string y = i.ToString();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").SetAttribute("value", y);

    i++;
    j++;

    if (j > 1000)
        timer1.Stop();
};

timer1.Start();
```

Comment: It still doesn't display everything that is going into the text box. It just takes longer to run.(I shortened it to only go to j < 100 and the sleep to 10.)